# Reading the inner text of an XML element using Go

Tags: xml, go

I'm trying to read an XML file in Go using the xml package (http://golang.org/pkg/xml/).

My problem is that I'm not sure how to read an element's inner text. I load the document in the xml.Parser and then call parser.Token() to move through the file. I check to see what the token is using the following:

```
token, err := parser.Token()
if element, ok := token.(xml.StartElement); ok {
  // process as a start element. I can read the element name and attributes here
}

if charData, ok := token.(xml.CharData); ok {
  // process as text. How do I read the text data?
}
```

The xml.CharData type is defined as:

```
type CharData []byte
```

but I can't seem to use the charData variable as an array of bytes to convert to a string. The only method defined for CharData is to copy the token, but that just gives another copy of a CharData variable. I've tried a few things but they don't compile:

```
innerText := string(charData)
innerText := string(charData[0:])
innerText := string(charData[0]) // this compiled but is not what I want
```

Is there another way to treat the xml.CharData variable as a slice of bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the language spec, you should be able to do `string([]byte(charData))`.

`[]byte` -> `string` is a special case for type conversion. Normally, the new type and original type must have the same underlying type (i.e. xml.CharData and []byte)

Comment: Amazing, that did the trick. I kept skimming the language spec for this but never saw it. Now I need to actually sit down and actually read the spec in detail.